# HTTP 404 the requested resource can not be found

Tags: servlets

I am getting HTTP 404 the requested resource can not be found.

I was executing my servlets comfortably a while ago. I compiled my last servlet and it compiled fine. Then I added it to my `web.xml` file and restarted my webserver and ever since I am getting the same error on all applets even the ones which were running fine earlier.
I checked the `web.xml` file for errors but it seems OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am getting HTTP 404 the requested resource can not be found.*

This can have several causes:

- URL is plain wrong. It has to match `<url-pattern>` of the servlet in `web.xml`.
- Mapping in `web.xml` is plain wrong. Read the server startup log for details.
- Servlet construction/initialization failed. Read the server startup log for details.
- Webapp startup failed completely. Read the server startup log for details.

Comment: but the servlets were working fine a while ago...and i didnt make any major changes in the xml file...

Comment: Read the server startup log for details.